# Editing Custom JS, CSS, etc. in WordPress using PhpStorm

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm

I just got thrown into a project involving WordPress with custom JavaScript, CSS and such, and I am using the Visual Composer plugin to edit the js and css, much to my dismay as there are no dev tools whatsoever.

I've got the site set up locally in PhpStorm, but I don't have a clue where the JS and CSS or whatever other editable code resides in files in WordPress. It's driving me crazy using the crappy UI with Visual Composer.

Can anyone tell me where to find these files? And, can anyone tell me where to put custom js files that need to be stored locally so that when they are called with:

```
<script src="meta-plugin.js"></script>
```

the file gets loaded.

Thanks for your help WordPress coders. I searched through the WordPress docs and couldn't find this info, so if it exists, if someone can just point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

Comment: Usually, all the css and js related to the theme are right in wp-content/themes. You should identify first the current theme..

Comment: I know the theme, and there are 70 or so js files in the themes/ronneby/assets/js/  directory. So, are you saying that it is one of these 70 files?